# Complex query filters in MongoDB via Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, nosql

Is there a way to query multiple fields and apply a filter to each one of them, in MongoDB, from NodeJS?

Example:

Imagine a collection with users profiles (name, surname, nick, age, etc...). Can I, somehow, query it like this:

```
db.collection("users").find({}).filter([
    {field: 'name', operator: 'startswith', value: 'Ji'},
    {field: 'surname', operator: 'contains', value: 'om'},
    {field: 'nick', operator: 'endswith', value: 'mmy'}
]); //Searching for Jimmy Thomson (alias jimmy)
```

EDIT:

I forgot to mention that I'm not looking for regex.

Comment: Have you looked at regexes? http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/regex/

Comment: @AndreasHultgren Sorry, I forgot to mention that I'm not looking for regex

Comment: what about http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/where/#op._S_where ? you can "craft" your filter expression with javascript so mongodb returns only the docs which match your filter options.

Comment: Actually, it looks like you are looking for a regex, as it's supported in MongoDB, whereas your request wouldn't work. And, because of the types of operations you want to perform, it's going to need to potentially search through all documents.

Comment: @WiredPrairie if there isn't anything better, which one should I use: regexp or $where? (I'd say regex sa of what I'm reading).

Comment: Using an anchored (starts with) regular expression has the best chance for reasonable performance with the `name` field, assuming it's indexed. You'll need to use the query `explain` functionality to validate that it's using the index. MongoDB isn't great at doing "text" searches, especially "contains" and "endswidth" style. If you need to do this frequently and efficiently, you've probably picked the wrong DB technology unfortunately.

Comment: @WiredPrairie oh noes :(  What about full text search? Can I search for a (couple of) word(s)? (I mean, not with a regex but with some native function)

Comment: They have a preview of full text search in the current release. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/text-search/  It's not production ready though.

Comment: @WiredPrairie maybe I should create a new question, but... I have something like that ```{question: 'text here', answers: [{answer: 'bla bla'}, {answer: 'bla bla'}, {answer: 'bla bla'}]}```. From 5 to 10 like those are going to be created each day from Monday to Friday, that means around 500-550/year. Are regex searches going to work fine (fast) in the next 10 or 20 years?

Comment: Maybe a new question to better explain the issue. It's about the total # of docs and whether the performance is acceptable to your users. At 1300-2600 docs a year (5-10 docs * 5 days * 52 weeks) that's not much data collectively.

Comment: Yes, I'll ask a new question. Thank you!